# Datapump import is unable to open the log file

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm trying to import the Oracle BISAMPLE.dmp schema and I've got this error ( unable to open the log file )

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument [to the `directory` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL907) is the name of an Oracle directory object, not a direct reference to the operating system directory.

If you do not already have an Oracle directory object pointing to that operating system directory, which has to be on the database server not a client machine, you (as DBA) will have to [create it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5007.htm), and grant privileges to any other Oracle users who will need to use it.

For example:

```
create directory MY_DATAPUMP_DIR as 'C:\installs\datapumpdir`;
```

and then

```
impdp directory=MY_DATAPUMP_DIR dumpfile=...
```

Alternatively you can move your `.dmp` file [to the default directory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL819), and either omit the `directory` parameter or specify the default for that, `DATA_PUMP_DIR`.

Also, note the big warning [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL891):

> Do not invoke Import as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users.